# How to convert leading zeros to decimal using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dataformat

I've got an excel file which columns are shown as follows:

```
|Calibre|Item|Aditivo|
|:----|:----|:----|
|015|4120|NO|
|018|4123|SI|
|2|4212|NO|
|075|4141|SI|
|500|4143|NO|
```

so I need to make a dataframe that show me the numbers that have leading zeros as decimal, just like this:

```
|Calibre|Item|Aditivo|
|:----|:----|:----|
|0.15|4120|NO|
|0.18|4123|SI|
|2|4212|NO|
|0.75|4141|SI|
|500|4143|NO|
```

I need to convert just some specific columns.
Currently the solution that I have found is this:

```
df=pd.read_excel('/content/file.xlsx',converters={'Calibre':str})
cal=[]
for i in df['Calibre']:
  if i[0]=='0':
    cal.append(float(i.replace('0','0.')))
  else:
    cal.append(int(i))
df['Calibre']=cal
```

But I really think that there is a better way to do this
(Also I can't edit the excel file)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `^` for start of strings and then convert values to floats, because if floats with integers then integers are converted to flats with `.0` suffix by default:

```
df=pd.read_excel('/content/file.xlsx',converters={'Calibre':str})

df['Calibre'] = df['Calibre'].str.replace('^0','0.').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your code to a function and use `.apply()`. I can't test it without a good sample dataset, but this will probably be more efficient than looping over every cell/row.

```
df=pd.read_excel('/content/file.xlsx',converters={'Calibre':str})
cal=[]

def convert_to_float(cell):
  if cell[0]=='0':
    return(float(i.replace('0','0.')))
  else:
    return(int(i))

df['Calibre'] = df['Calibre'].apply(convert_to_float, axis=1)
```